# Formato fecha JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date

Estoy teniendo problemas al formatear la fecha.
Por cuestión de versión, no puedo definir un campo tipo date, así que debo definirlo tipo `datetime` y me agrega varios 0 al final.
Obtengo de un json esto:

```
Object {fecha_desde: "2017-01-01 00:00:00.000", fecha_hasta: "2017-04-30 00:00:00.000"}
```

Y mi intento es este:

```
<script>
          $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#cuatrimestre').on('change',function(){
                var cuatrimestre = $(this).val();
                $.ajax({
                    url : "getCuatri.php",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    type: 'POST',
                    async : false,
                    data : { cuatrimestre : cuatrimestre},
                    success : function(data) {
                        console.log(data)
                        //userData = JSON.parse(data);
                        var desde = String(data.fecha_desde).split('-');
                        var fechaDesde = desde[1] + '-' + desde[2] + '-' + desde[0];
                        $('#desde').val(fechaDesde);
                        var hasta = String(data.fecha_hasta).split('-');
                        var fechaHasta = hasta[1] + '-' + hasta[2] + '-' + hasta[0];
                        $('#hasta').val(fechaHasta);
                        //$('#hasta').val(data.fecha_hasta);
                    }
                }); 
            });
         });
        </script>
```

Pero obtengo esto:

```
01-01 00:00:00.000-2017
04-30 00:00:00.000-2017
```

En el modo test que tengo el campo de tipo date, me funciona perfecto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esto no funciona como esperas:

```
String(data.fecha_desde).split('-');
```

Ya que separará tres grupos, por eso se ve el tiempo junto con el mes:

```
mes / dia / año tiempo
```

Puedes convertir la fecha en texto a un objeto Date y luego el método [`toLocaleString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) para obtener solo el mes, día y año de la fecha. También puedes usar [moment](https://momentjs.com). El siguiente ejemplo usa ambas formas.

**Ejemplo**

```js
let fechas = {
  desde: '2017-01-01 00:00:00.000',
  hasta: '2017-04-30 00:00:00.000'
};

let desde = parseDate(fechas.desde);
let hasta = moment(fechas.hasta).format('MM-DD-YYYY');

console.log('Desde:', desde);
console.log('Hasta (moment):', hasta);
  
function parseDate (isodate) {
  return (
    new Date(isodate)
      .toLocaleString('en-US', {
        month: '2-digit',
        day: '2-digit',
        year: 'numeric'
      })
      .replace(/\//g, '-')
  );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Impecable! Muchas gracias

Answer (score 2):

Convierte el objeto a Date de esta manera

```
var desde = new Date(data.fecha_desde);
```

y para obtener el valor puedes usar `.toLocaleDateString()` que te devolverá la fecha en formato `d/m/yyyy`

Si quieres cambiar de formato en este caso `dd/mm/yyyy` habria que seleccionar una Zona en mi caso `es-MX` y después las opciones a considerar:

```
{year: 'numeric', month: '2-digit', day: '2-digit' }
```

para mas informacion sobre las opciones [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString)

Te dejo tu ejemplo

```js
var data = {fecha_desde: "2017-01-01 00:00:00.000", fecha_hasta: "2017-04-30 00:00:00.000"}

console.log(data)
//userData = JSON.parse(data);

var options = {year: 'numeric', month: '2-digit', day: '2-digit' };

var desde = new Date(data.fecha_desde);
console.log(desde.toLocaleDateString("es-MX", options))
$('#desde').val(desde);

var hasta = new Date(data.fecha_hasta);
console.log(hasta.toLocaleDateString("es-MX", options))
$('#hasta').val(hasta);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias. 
Otra pregunta, es posible agregar dos digitos?
Ejemplo: 01/01/2017 y 30/04/2017

Comment: @GAL Si, pero habría que ponerle un formato de ora local, es decir poner una zona (es-MX) y después las opciones para el formato. He editado la respuesta