# Convertir objeto New Date a formato fecha yyyy/mm/dd JavaScript

Tags: javascript

hay alguna manera de convertir un objeto new Date() a un formato yyyy/mm/dd o dd/mm/yyyy?

```
let fechaprueba = new Date()
```

Me entrega lo siguiente en un console.log **Wed Feb 09 2022 13:48:49 GMT-0700 (hora estándar del Pacífico de México)**
Hay alguna manera de convertirlo a otro formato?
la única opción que se me ocurre es ir concatenando en una variable, pero quisiera saber si hay alguna otra manera de realizarlo

```
let fechaprueba = new Date()
let fechaFormateada = fechaprueba.getDate() + '/' + fechaprueba.getMonth() + '/' + fechaprueba.getFullYear()
```

Esa es mi opción pero hay alguna otra manera más correcta de realizarlo?

Comment: Hola, puedes revisar la documentación de moment.js https://momentjs.com/ encontraras como manipular la fecha que tienes

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Formato fecha JavaScript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/53481/formato-fecha-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo más visual:

```
const date = new Date();

let day = date.getDate();
let month = date.getMonth() + 1;
let fullYear = date.getFullYear();

//Usamos la interpolación de variables

let fecha = `${day}/${month}/${fullYear}`;
console.log(fecha);
```

Salu2